# How to modify transparent ratio?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a transparent picture, and I read it by:

```
img=cv2.read("myimg.png",-1)
```

But now I want to modify the level of transparent of this object (**50%** or **60%**).

How could we can do that?

Please help me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to modify the alpha channels of the image:

```
# modify the alpha channel
img[:,:,3] = img[:,:,3] // 2
```

This method is somewhat difficult to use with arbitrary transparency coefficient. So we can do

```
img_copy = np.copy(img)

// totally transparent
img_copy[:,:,3] = 0

// add weighted
img = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.6, img_copy, 0.4, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A JPEG image does not give you the alpha channel where transparency could be modified as in a PNG.